# Como ejecutar un mismo método simultáneamente a elementos en un array

Tags: c#, hilos

La idea está en ejecutar los metodos dentro del foreach a la vez y no que termine la ejecucion del 1ero para comenzar con el resto.

```
using System;

namespace MemoryStreamConsoleApp
{
   class Program
   {
     metodo_1(string source, string target);
        
        void Copy()
        {
           foreach (var target in array){
             metodo_1(source, target);
             metodo_1(source, target);
           }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Tenes varias formas de ejecutar metodos en forma paralela. En tu caso como queres recorrer un array e ir ejecutando, lo mejor seria usar `Parallel.Foreach`, si tenes 100 registros, no los va a ejecutar a todos al mismo tiempo porque el Sistema operativo que estes usando va a manejar de manera optima cuanto tiempo e hilos te permite usar, podes ejecutar 5 metodos a la vez como 20, todo depende del S.O.

```
Parallel.Foreach(array, (target)=> {
         metodo_1(source, target);
       })
```

No dejaste claro de donde sale el parametro `source` lo cual romperia el metodo asi tal cual te lo dejo.

Te dejo la documentacion oficial.

https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/parallel-programming/how-to-write-a-simple-parallel-foreach-loop